# Qos implementation

Tags: qos, gre

I want to implement Qos on a GRE tunnel and want to give priority to a destination IP 1.1.1.1 of a system from our site using WAN link. I will match the traffic through an ACL in class-map in which source IP will be any and destination IP will be 1.1.1.1

I have following questions:

Can I apply service-policy on a tunnel interface?

Will routers including ISP and ours through out the network to destination will give priority to the packets with destination of IP 1.1.1.1 ?

If it is possible, how will I test if everything is working fine after configuration?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a specific agreement with your ISP and the whole path is under the control of you and your ISP, no there's no QoS on the Internet.

All Internet router will simply ignore all QoS markers on your packet.

If you have a tunnel, then you can discriminate between the different flows that pass through the tunnel and give priority to some traffic.

Comment: If there is gre tunnel between my site and the main office, then will the routers along the way give priority as I have declared on A end of the tunnel?

Comment: No. First they will not see the QoS markers since they are in a packet that is encapsulated, and second, even if they see a QoS marker they will ignore it.

Comment: So is there a way to implement Qos (always give priority) when a traffic arrives at site router for a specific destination IP that is present at main office?